# showing blocks only when user is logged in

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, custom

I have created one custom block which I wants to show only when some user has logged in my website. Lets say the name of my block is 'sample_block' . How can I display 'sample_block' only when some user has logged in to my website?

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options.
The clean one is to include it in the `customer_logged_in` layout handle in the layout file.
Something like this.

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="left"> <!-- or right, header, content, footer -->
        <block type="...">....</block> <!-- your block declaration here -->
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

Second option, a bit dirty but it works.
Add an if statement at the top of the template that renders the block.

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) : ?>
    <!-- your html template here -->
<?php endif;?>
```

This second option can be implemented a little different if you have a block class for your template.
Just add the `_toHtml()` method.

```
protected function _toHtml() {
    if (!if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())) {
        return '';
    }
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

This makes the block appear only for logged in customer independent of the template you use for the block.

Comment: I tried `<customer_logged_in>` now nothing shows at all.

Comment: Check for syntax errors.